# 5 people call one of 4 hospitals each. each hospital has a doctor. What is the probability they didn't all call the same doctor?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> In a certain city there are 4 veterinary hospitals. Each hospital has
>   a doctor working during the night. Certain night, 5 animals get sick
>   and their owners called one of these hospitals each, randomly,
>   requesting that a vet come to their house.
>
> What is the probability the owners didn't all call the same vet?

I did:

- probability they all called the same hospital/vet:$$\frac{1}{4}*\frac{1}{4}*\frac{1}{4}*\frac{1}{4}*\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{1024}$$
- total minus the above = $$1 - \frac{1}{1024} = 0.9990$$

But my book says the solution is $\frac{255}{256}$.

What did I do wrong?
It can also be that I am right and my book's solution is an approximate answer. The values are very similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you calculated is the probability that all of them call hospital $1$. But you need to consider the probabilities they call hospitals $2,3$ and $4$ also.

Comment: $\frac{4}{4}*\frac{1}{4}*\frac{1}{4}*\frac{1}{4}*\frac{1}{4}= \frac{4}{4^5}$ and so $1-\frac{4}{1024}=\frac{255}{256}$. Thanks

Comment: you are welcome.